# POST request Fetch API prevent redirect

Tags: javascript, html, forms, http-post, fetch-api

So i want to make a pure html and javascript form and submit it to server.

Here is my html form code:

```
<form id="email-signup" action="http://www.server.com" method="post">
    <input id="firstname-input" type="hidden" name="firstname" value="">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Input Email">
    <input type="hidden" name="campaign[id]" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="campaign[name]" value="Text Campaign">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And here is my javascript code:

```
var element = document.getElementById("email-signup");
element.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  fetch("http://www.endpoint.api", {
    method: "POST",
    body: new FormData(document.getElementById('email-signup'))
  })
})
  .then(() => {
  alert('Selamat email anda sudah terdaftar!')
})
```

The problem is, whenever i submit an email to that form it redirects me to a new page with a response of success. I want to prevent that to happen and instead it will pop up an alert that tells me the email submission is succeeded.

Comment: anything in the developer tools console to suggest that the javascript may not even be running? like, an error or soemthing?

Comment: Is it possible there is server-side code at `http://www.server.com` that is causing a redirect when posted? If there is server-side code, please post it here.

Comment: @NightOwl888 `http://ae683b14f332321a8t16b02dba7d519b-2052846694.ap-southeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com/` actually this is the api. Maybe it's the one that causing the redirect then?

Comment: @JaromandaX there is no error in developer tools console. The email that it put on that form is successfully stored in the servers. But it still redirect me when i succeeded submit the email. I think how i post the email from the FormData is just fine hmmm

Comment: considering `addEventListener` doesn't return an object with a `.then` method, I highly doubt you don't have an error in the developer tools console - perhaps you don't know what you're looking for ... add `console.log("in handler");` just after `event.preventDefault();` - if that doesn't appear in the console, then it's clear your handler isn't being called

Answer (score 0):

You're putting the `.then` in the wrong place - put it right after the `fetch`, not after the event listener.

```
var element = document.getElementById("email-signup");
element.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  fetch("", {
    method: "POST",
    body: new FormData(document.getElementById('email-signup'))
  }).then((res) => {
    if (res.ok) alert('Selamat email anda sudah terdaftar!')
  })
})
```

Consistent indentation will help you avoid problems like this in the future. (see your question, I fixed the formatting - should be pretty clear what the problem was now)

Comment: Yups, i edit the code right before your answer. But the problem is still there. It still redirects me to a new page instead popping up the alert.

Comment: Check your browser console for errors - if there are problems, it's not with the code here, because if the script runs, the `event.preventDefault()` will prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: There is no errors in browser console indicating that my fetch POST is error, because the email is smoothly stored in my servers. But it still redirects me and even it's not showing the console.log that i put inside .then() right after. I even give .catch() if there is any more errors

Comment: look for any error, at all, when you load the page, not when you submit the form

Comment: @AdithWidyaPradipta The native form POST will still function normally (and send the email to your server, and redirect the page) even if there are Javascript errors.

Comment: @JaromandaX i only see a warning, not an error i think:


`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.hijup.com/id/lp/testemail' was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form that targets an insecure endpoint 'http://ae683b13f234311e6a26b02cba7d519b-2052846694.ap-southeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com/'. This endpoint should be made available over a secure connection.`

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, you are putting JavaScript code before HTML and .then() after EventListner.

The solution will be to place JavaScript code after HTML and place .then() just after fetch.

```
    <form id="email-signup" action="http://www.server.com" method="post">
        <input id="firstname-input" type="hidden" name="firstname" value="">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Input Email">
        <input type="hidden" name="campaign[id]" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="campaign[name]" value="Text Campaign">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

<script>
    var element = document.getElementById("email-signup");
    element.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        fetch("", {
            method: "POST",
            body: new FormData(document.getElementById('email-signup'))
            }).then(() => {
            alert('Selamat email anda sudah terdaftar!')
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: OP commented `there is no error in developer tools console` - clearly there would be an error if what you say is right ... however, I believe you are right, I don't believe there is no error in the console

Comment: yes there is some errors in the console. but its not related to the form and the endpoint. The errors come from other tools `emarsys` and is not the tools i use for the email signup. I use moengage and optimonk. @JaromandaX