# Express: If HTML Form Post Request fails, how I display error on same HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, express

I can't find anything about this online. I can see examples of if request fails, set a status code e.g. 404 and send a message. But, that will only be visible in the browser network tab.

I have a input text box. User enters text and clicks Submit button. If post request fails, I simply want to stop the request, remain on same web page and display an error like "User not found". How do I go about implementing this.

HTML:

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/getuser" method="POST">
        <input id="" placeholder="" name="userid", type="text" required minlength="2"> 
        <div class="button">
            <button id="submit" type="submit" class="search button">Update User</button>
        </form>    
        </input>
```

Express:

```
app.post('/getuser', runAsyncWrapper(async(req, res) => {
  const userID = await getUserID(req.body.userid);
  // if(!userID) {
  // How do I display error on web page?
  // }
  res.redirect(`${profile.username}`)
```

Comment: You need to use a bit of ajax or fetch, and preventDefault on your form post.   I'd be surprised if there isn't something on Stack Overflow on this.  I'll see if I can find something.

Comment: This might help you -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49663596/post-request-fetch-api-prevent-redirect/49663790  Can't mark as duplicate, but the concept on how to handle post with fetch should get you started.

Comment: In addition to what Keith suggested, the fundamental point you've seem to miss is that a POST request from a form submission is a stateless, one-way transfer from the client (browser) to the server. Once the submit button is pressed, the client forgets completely about the server. This means there is no way to "update the page" when using a form with a submit as you've shown. Keith points out the use of fetch - which allows you to have control over the communication to the server and react to that 404 within the client.

Comment: Ok, so form post request is wrong for what I want, will start looking at Ajax/Fetch, thanks.

Comment: @George  It depends,.  you can do this without fetch, you basically make your POST request return another HTML page with the FORM again with the error on.  This is how it was done before AJax/Fetch became the norm.   Its how you would still do it now if you wanted it to work on browsers with Javascript disabled.